# Ubuntu 12.10 driver for Epson XP-202

Tags: 12.10, drivers, printing, epson

Can anyone advise me if there is a printer driver for an Epson XP-202 printer to work with Ubuntu 12.10?

If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried the one Epson provides [on their website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)? I've found a few using `XP-202` as search keyword.

Comment: @gertvdijk Why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Epson provides Linux drivers [on their website](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX). I've found a few using `XP-202` as a search keyword. I'm not able to verify if they work with Ubuntu 12.10, as I don't own this device.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install epson-inkjet-printer-201202w
```

It seems that since Ubuntu 11.04, it should install automatically on plug.

It did work for me before, until I installed some package which messed it up.

The easiest way to fix it was to install the correct package manually. I found it with:

```
apt-cache search epson | grep 202
```

and it gives:

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201202w - Epson XP-30/102/202/205 Series - Epson Inkjet Printer Driv
```