# What driver do I needin order to install Epson XP202 all in one printer?

Tags: drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.10 driver for Epson XP-202](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227097/ubuntu-12-10-driver-for-epson-xp-202)

What driver do I need to install Epson XP202 all in one printer? Would it be easier to change my printer and buy HP?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "XP-202" at http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Have you tried just plugging it in with an USB cable and see if it "just works"?