# Can I print to an Epson Expression XP-102?

Tags: printing, epson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.10 driver for Epson XP-202](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227097/ubuntu-12-10-driver-for-epson-xp-202)

I own a Epson Expression XP-102, but I cannot find a way to make it work.

I am new to Ubuntu.

Is there any way to make print to the Epson Expression?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/231911/88802) applies for your printer as well. So, marking as possible duplicate: [Ubuntu 12.10 driver for Epson XP-202](http://askubuntu.com/q/227097/88802)

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble too. If you go to the link below and download one of the drivers at the bottom of the page marked packages (I used the top one of the six), this gets the printer going. I am yet to get the scanner going but will let you know if I suss this out.

http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/lsb/epson-inkjet/escpr/

Hope this helps,

Miles